# Proper way to use Google Calendar in an Android app?

Tags: android-studio, google-calendar-api

My application must create events in a user's Google Calendar, however I'm unsure of how to implement this. My app uses Google Sign-in.

I've looked online and there seem to be multiple APIs that Google provides, but I'm not sure which is appropriate For example, do I use the Google Calendar API, the Calendar Provider API, or Google Play Services? Also, can the inserting of events be handled directly on the app, or should it be done on something like a Heroku server?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For starters, you can read from the Calendar Provider [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider). The documentation should contain most of the information you need to build a starter app.

Comment: @Jacque I've read it, but it doesn't seem to be specific to Google Calendar, but instead alters the phone's local calendar.